# Width of div with position:absolute content

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have div without fixed width (this `div` should have width as it's content) in it there is div with `position:absolute` and fixed width, but relative div has `0px` width, how I can fix it?

```html
<div class="container" style="position:relative">
  <div class="innerContainer" style="position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 10px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a snippen with relevant code?

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are completely removed from the document flow. So, you have to specify a width for the parent.

Comment: Absolute positioned divs are positioned *in relation* to their relative ancestor  BUT they do not form part of the layout and so do not contribute to the width or height of the ancestor.

Comment: Why the need of absolute positioned div`s ?

Comment: They should move on 3dp on the left and 3dp on the bottom of each other but should  be in parrent div

Comment: So why can't you use `margin` or `padding`?

Comment: Not quite sure what that means, please post an image showing how you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An absolute positioned div is taken out of the normal flow and as such doesn't effect, in this case, its parent height. The parent will display as there were no content (0px high).

In your case, you need to give your parent (container) a height big enough for the absolute position content to fit or fill it with normal flowed content, and have the inner div positioned at left and bottom like this.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.innerContainer {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px; 
  height: 10px;
  background: darkgray;
}
.innerContainer:nth-child(2) {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer"></div>
  <div class="innerContainer"></div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer"></div>
  <div class="innerContainer"></div>
  This has text that sizes itself<br>
  This has text that sizes itself<br>
  This has text that sizes itself<br>
</div>
```